# Indexing a list of dictionaries for a relating value

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a 4 dictionaries which have been defined into a list

```
dict1 = {'A':'B'}
dict2 = {'C':'D'}
dict3 = {'E':'F'}
dict4 = {'G':'H'}

list = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]

value = 'D'

print (the relating value to D)
```

using the list of dictionaries I would like to index it for the relating value of D (which is 'C').

is this possible?

note: the list doesn't have to be used, the program just needs to find the relating value of C by going through the 4 dictionaries in one way or another.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, you want to print the key associated with the value `"D"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries. A straightforward way would be to loop over the list, and search for desired value using -

> dict.iteritems()

which iterates over the dictionary and returns the 'key':'value' pair as a tuple (key,value). So all thats left to do is search for a desired value and return the associated key. Here is a quick code I tried. Also this should work for dictionaries with any number of key value pairs (I hope).

```
dict1 = {'A':'B'}
dict2 = {'C':'D'}
dict3 = {'E':'F'}
dict4 = {'G':'H'}

list = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]

def find_in_dict(dictx,search_parameter):
    for x,y in dictx.iteritems():
        if y == search_parameter:
            return x

for i in range(list.__len__()):
    my_key = find_in_dict(list[i], "D")
    print my_key or "No key found"
```

On a different note, such a usage of dictionaries is little awkward for me, as it defeats the purpose of having a KEY as an index for an associated VALUE. But anyway, its just my opinion and I am not aware of your use case. Hope it helps.